# SUM Values within SQL based on a column

Tags: sql, postgresql, conditional-aggregation

I have a table like below:

[image]

I want to transform the data so that the end product actually looks like this:

[image]

This is easily done within Excel but i would like to be able to do this via SQL so i can automate a report.

I have tried the below code which doesn't work:

```
SELECT 
SKU,
SUM(totals,ordered = 'Web') as Web_orders,
SUM(totals,ordered = 'App') as App_orders

FROM A

GROUP BY SKU
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of case expressions:

```
SELECT
  sku,
  SUM(case when ordered = 'web' then totals else 0 end) as "web",
  SUM(case when ordered = 'app' then totals else 0 end) as "app"
FROM A
GROUP BY sku
```

Answer (score 2):

This will work:

```
SELECT 
SKU,
SUM(totals) filter (where ordered='web') as Web_orders,
SUM(totals) filter (where ordered='app') as App_orders
FROM A

GROUP BY SKU
ORDER by SKU;
```

If you want the uppercase letters you need to surround the column names with "".